# Dart is crashing on startup

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So I was able to recompile Gazebo with Dart, but I keep getting this bizarre error:

***** Internal Program Error - assertion (dartChildLink.get() != __null) failed in virtual void gazebo::physics::DARTJoint::Init():

on loading a world. What should I do? Did I miscompile Dart? Is it a problem on Gazebo's side? This is Gazebo 1.4 btw.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9012/dart-is-crashing-on-startup/) by [Skylion](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1252/skylion/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Apparently, Gazebo will crash if you try to fix a model to the world frame and load the world with the Dart engine. I have submitted a ticket on this issue.

---

Originally posted by [Skylion](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1252/skylion/) with karma: 5 on 2015-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0